# Python Dictionary Contains List as a Value - How to add the value for each key?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

I have extracted a key and a list of values for each key and pushed them into a dictionary. My next step is to add all the values together for each list per key then assign those values to a dictionary. Below is an example of my dictionary currently:

```
{'1/10/20': [42, 22, 462, 60], '1/11/20': [1, 7, 20], '1/12/20': [1238, 12, 984, 75, 102]
```

Hope to achieve:

```
{'1/10/20': 586, '1/11/20': 28, '1/12/20': 2411}
```

I pulled the data using pandas group by function:

```
total = df.groupby('DateIn')['TotalSheet'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

Comment: df.groupby('DateIn')['TotalSheet'].sum().to_dict()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I guess a simple for loop will suffice.

```
x = {'1/10/20': [42, 22, 462, 60], '1/11/20': [1, 7, 20], '1/12/20': [1238, 12, 984, 75, 102]}

for item in x.keys():
    x[item] = sum(x[item])
print(x)
```

You will get the desired output, i.e,

```
{'1/10/20': 586, '1/11/20': 28, '1/12/20': 2411}
```

Cheers.

Comment: Actually, that is not considered very "pythonic". dict comprehension is the way to solve this in Python.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Well not everyone has the same way of doing things :)

Comment: Sure, and everyone is entitled to their own style. However, I think answers on SO should not only provide technically correct solutions, but should also take into account conventions, because following conventions might be important in a cooperative environment. And imho using dict comprehension in such a situation is a pretty strong Python style convention.

Answer (score 3):

With `Pandas` you can do this:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(dict([(k,pd.Series(v)) for k,v in d.items()])).T.sum(axis=1).to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'1/10/20': 586, '1/11/20': 28, '1/12/20': 2411}
```

**OR**

If you are looking for Python: can use `dict comprehension`:

```
d = {'1/10/20': [42, 22, 462, 60], '1/11/20': [1, 7, 20], '1/12/20': [1238, 12, 984, 75, 102]}

{k:sum(v) for k,v in d.items()}
```

**Output:**

```
{'1/10/20': 586, '1/11/20': 28, '1/12/20': 2411}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the pandas background and just answering the question how to get the desired dictionary from the given dictionary, this is a good use case for Python's dict comprehension:

```
result = {
   key: sum(l)
   for key, l in original_dict.items()
}
```